# Malayalam Heading for a custom listview in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a custom listview like this in my app, without the heading part. Now I need to add a heading at the top of my listview as shown in the image. How can this be added to my custom listview. The custom listview is a fragment activity. One thing to be noted is that I want the heading to be displayed in malayalam (Utf-8) and not in english (ascii). The designation and name in my custom listview are in malayalam. And I have done this using Typeface in my app. But I don't know how to display a heading in malayalam in custom listview. Thanks in advance..

[image]

This is the code of my customlistviewadapter.class.

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem>{

Typeface tf;
 Context context;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
            List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView name;
        TextView designation;
        TextView phonenumber;
       // Helper help=new Helper(context);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        ImageButton call,sms;
        final RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        final LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"MLKR0NTT.TTF");

            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.designation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.phonenumber=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.name.setText(rowItem.getName());
        holder.designation.setText(rowItem.getDesignation());
        holder.name.setTypeface(tf);
        holder.designation.setTypeface(tf);
        holder.phonenumber.setText(rowItem.getPhone());
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(rowItem.getImage());
        call=(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.callbutton);
        sms=(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.smsbutton);
        sms.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("sms:"+rowItem.getPhone())); 
                        smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "");
                                context.startActivity(smsIntent);



            }
        });
        call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Calling...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +rowItem.getPhone()));
                        context.startActivity(intent);                  



            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take image of text in whichever language yo need and then use addHeaderView(Your View here) method of listview by passing that view...

Comment: Instead of using image, is there any way to use contents inside the String variables.

Comment: Using an image will reduce your programming efforts!

Comment: I have the text to show as heading which is stored in a string variable. So It's easier for me to use string variables